# Selenium Jana- How to get the desired value from inside a <i> tag

Tags: java, selenium, automation

```
<i data-html="true" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" data-original-title="Backend Offer Details" data-content="<dl class='dl-horizontal itemCodeHolder'><dt>Code : </dt><dd>BPAZ3XG</dd><dt>SOC : </dt><dd>No Matching SOC</dd></dl>" data-toggle="popover" class="icon-info-sign boPopover"></i>
```

How to get a value from something like this. This is a tool-tip and I want the to get BPAZ3XG from the above tag. How is it possible in Selenium.

Comment: That value is like the unique code n its dynamic to each new data... So I need something that will get me that value although it is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have a locator for the `i` element or not yet so I added code for one in case you didn't. For the `i` locator, I am assuming that the `data-original-title='Backend Offer Details'` is unique on the page. If it isn't, you'll have to adjust it.

Basically I find the `i` element, get the `data-content` attribute (which is a small HTML/XML snippet), and then look for the text in the *first* `dd` tag. NOTE: there are *two* `dd` tags in the data-content HTML snippet.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i[data-original-title='Backend Offer Details']"));
String dataContent = element.getAttribute("data-content");
System.out.println(dataContent.substring(dataContent.indexOf("<dd>") + 4, dataContent.indexOf("</dd>")));
```

Answer (score -1):

if your target element "BPAZ3XG" is having no duplicates in web application, you can try with contains text, as i mentioned below

```
//*[contains(text(),'BPAZ3XG')]
```

To break this down,

*is a selector that matches any element (i.e. tag) -- it returns a node-set.

The [] are a conditional that operates on each individual node in that node set. It matches if any of the individual nodes it operates on match the conditions inside the brackets.

text() is a selector that matches all of the text nodes that are children of the context node -- it returns a node set.

contains is a function that operates on a string. If it is passed a node set, the node set is converted into a string by returning the string-value of the node in the node-set that is first in document order

Comment: The way this post is written makes it seem like a comment, not an answer.  Can you edit your answer to be more concrete?

Comment: Thanks all for advising me, i have made changes in my answer.